# css - change color when hover on sibiling

Tags: html, css

I have an image and header in my html :

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-underline-hover">
 <a class="rightImg">
    <img class="img-responsive icon-img homepage-icon" src="{{asset('assets/img/homepage/icons/1.png')}}" alt="Greece-1173 - Temple of Athena by Dennis Jarvis, on Flickr">
     <h3 class = "gray-color homepage-icon-detail">perfume </h3>
 </a>
</div>
```

I want to changing *h3* color when I hover *img*. Here I used on my css :

```
.homepage-icon-detail .homepage-icon:hover {
    color: hsl(288, 63%, 28%);
}
```

But it doesn't work. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that hover with the below CSS code. You can access sibling using '+' in CSS

```
.homepage-icon:hover +.homepage-icon-detail {
    color: hsl(288, 63%, 28%);
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/37vqsLj3/)

Answer (score 1):

A rather straight forward way of doing it:

```
a.rightImg:hover, a.rightImg:active {
  color: hsl(288, 63%, 28%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also base your styling on your structure, instead of explicitly using class names. That way your HTML will have better readability, since you will utilise fewer classes.

For example;

```
a.rightImg img:hover + h3 { color: hsl(288, 63%, 28%); }
```