# Hover on header tag and transform image

Tags: html, css

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248039/css-change-color-when-hover-on-sibiling). Here another issue to complement that: 
I have an image and header in my html

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 no-underline-hover">
 <a class="rightImg">
    <img class="img-responsive icon-img homepage-icon" src="{{asset('assets/img/homepage/icons/1.png')}}" alt="Greece-1173 - Temple of Athena by Dennis Jarvis, on Flickr">
     <h3 class = "gray-color homepage-icon-detail">perfume </h3>
 </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.homepage-icon:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
}
.homepage-icon {
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.homepage-icon:hover +.homepage-icon-detail {
    color: hsl(288, 63%, 28%);
    transform: scale(1.1);

}
h3.homepage-icon-detail:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    color: hsl(288, 63%, 28%);
}
h3.homepage-icon-detail:hover + .homepage-icon{
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
}
```

Whenever I hover `homepage-icon` , `h3`'s color is changing. What I want to change is the icon size when I hover `h3`. Any suggestion?

Comment: ok , how to do this with AngularJs?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
h3:hover + .homepage-icon{
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
}

homepage-icon:hover ~ h3{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think You have to do this way:

```
h3:hover .homepage-icon{
    transform: scale(1.03, 1.03);
}
```

and

```
homepage-icon:hover h3{
    color:white;
}
```